# How to enable bootstrap rtl in scss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5, rtlcss, bootstrap-rtl

I coded based on the [documents](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/) in this link. But my code doesn't work in SCSS.

this is my main.scss.

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

body {
  background: red #{"/* rtl:blue */"};
}
```

and this is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="compiled.css">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test Test Test</h1>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may not be clear in the Bootstrap 5 docs, but [RTLCSS](https://rtlcss.com/) is a JS module that is used compile *special RTLCSS formatted CSS* to *CSS*. For example,

RTLCSS with value directive:

```
body {
  background: red /*rtl:blue*/;
}
```

CSS result (*after processing with RTLCSS*):

```
body {
  background: blue;
}
```

You can try this on this [RTLCSS playground](https://rtlcss.com/playground)

**Browsers don't understand the RTLCSS, they only understand CSS**

RTLCSS is also different than using `dir="rtl"`. Using "dir=rtl" simply [tells the browser the "directionality of the element's text"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir).

**How Bootstrap 5 implements RTL support**

Looking at [Bootstrap 5 compiled CSS files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/contents/#css-files) you'll see there is now a `bootstrap.rtl.min.css` file. Bootstrap is using RTLCSS to process/compile the SASS generated LTR CSS. Here's how the `bootstrap.rtl.(min.)css` files are generated by Bootstrap...

1. SASS source files
2. Compile using SASS generates standard LTR CSS (`bootstrap.css`) that contains comments with special RTLCSS directives
3. Post process `bootstrap.css` using RTLCSS module
4. Result is `bootstrap.rtl.css` which contains CSS rules that re-orient components like breadcrumbs, dropdowns, carousel, etc... for RTL support. The generated `bootstrap.rtl.css` also reverses the direction of "start" and "end" for padding, margins, floats, etc...

So the build process is basically...

`SASS files` > `compile with SASS` > `boostrap.css` (contains special RTLCSS directives in comments) > `compile with RTLCSS` > `boostrap.rtl.css`

As you can [see here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/#custom-rtl-values), you can use SASS to change the generated CSS, but that generated CSS would still need to be post processed using RTLCSS in order to generate CSS rules that will work in the browser...

SASS:

```
$font-weight-bold: 700 #{/* rtl:600 */} !default;
```

Which would output to the following for our default CSS and RTL CSS:

```
/* bootstrap.css */
dt {
  font-weight: 700 /* rtl:600 */;
}

/* bootstrap.rtl.css */
dt {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Therefore, you need to post process using RTLCSS to get what you expect in `compiled.css`. If you didn't want to use RTLCSS like Bootstrap does, you could simply add CSS rules with the `dir=rtl` selectors..

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}

body[dir='rtl'] {
    direction: rtl;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/M7SuLr4Pi5)

Comment: does not generate any RTL css. Here, I am confused. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32385#issuecomment-987742939

Comment: I don't really understand the comment. RTLCSS is a CSS processor.. it's separate from Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/rtl/#approach

Answer (score 1):

Here are simple steps, you can check bootstrap package.json
Files must be modified to suit your business

[Read File](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/package.json)

### Step 1

###### file package.json

```json
{
    "name": "app-name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {},
    "scripts": {
        "css-compile": "sass --style expanded --source-map --embed-sources --no-error-css src/scss/:asset/css/",
        "css-rtl": "cross-env NODE_ENV=RTL postcss --config config/postcss.config.js --dir \"asset/css\" --ext \".rtl.css\" \"asset/css/*.css\" \"!asset/css/*.min.css\" \"!asset/css/*.rtl.css\"",
        "css": "npm-run-all css-compile css-prefix css-rtl css-minify",
        "css-prefix": "npm-run-all --aggregate-output --parallel css-prefix-*",
        "css-prefix-main": "postcss --config config/postcss.config.js --replace \"asset/css/*.css\" \"!asset/css/*.rtl*.css\" \"!asset/css/*.min.css\"",
        "css-minify": "npm-run-all --aggregate-output --parallel css-minify-*",
        "css-minify-main": "cleancss -O1 --format breakWith=lf --with-rebase --source-map --source-map-inline-sources --output asset/css/ --batch --batch-suffix \".min\" \"asset/css/*.css\" \"!asset/css/*.min.css\" \"!asset/css/*rtl*.css\"",
        "css-minify-rtl": "cleancss -O1 --format breakWith=lf --with-rebase --source-map --source-map-inline-sources --output asset/css/ --batch --batch-suffix \".min\" \"asset/css/*rtl.css\" \"!asset/css/*.min.css\""
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "postcss": "^8.3.6",
        "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
        "rtlcss": "^3.3.0",
        "sass": "^1.41.0"
    },
    "files": [
        "asset/{css}/*.{css,map}",
        "src/scss/**/*.scss"
    ]
}
```

### Step 2

###### File config/postcss.config.js

[Read Folder Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/main/build)

```js
"use strict";

module.exports = (ctx) => {
  return {
    plugins: {
      autoprefixer: {
        cascade: false,
      },
      rtlcss: ctx.env === "RTL" ? {} : false,
    },
  };
};
```

### Step 3

packages installation

```patch
npm install
```

### Step 4

production

```patch
npm run css
```

### output

- app.css
- app.css.map
- app.min.css
- app.min.css.map
- app.rtl.css
- app.rtl.css.map
- app.rtl.min.css
- app.rtl.min.css.map